# Dynamic Links in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

currently I'm working on static website, so I'm using jekyll to generate it. To have a nice structure and fancy URLs, I use permalinks.

```
permalink: /impressum/
```

So for example the impressum.html is rendered to impressum/index.html. And in my HTML i can simply link to that file with

```
<a href="/impressum">
```

That works for me very well. But you know, I'm a programmer. What if I want for example to change the URL to /imprint/? Well, I can change the permalink without any problems. But what's about all the other links on the site? Yeah, sure, I can use the search & replace function of my editor to change the linked URLs and check the whole site with a site checker for broken links, but that's not the fancy way I want to go. That's why I tried to create some kind of global variables with the permalink.

_config.yml:

```
lnk_impressum: /impressum/
```

impressum.html

```
---
layout: layout
title: Your New Jekyll Site
permalink: {{ site.lnk_impressum }}
---
```

But that does not work. I get this error:

```
Generating... error: no implicit conversion of Hash into String. Use --trace to view backtrace
```

So what's wrong or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to place Liquid tags inside the YAML Frontmatter or _config files, per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14650794/663607).

Something else you could try is based on the approach used by the [documentation pages for Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs), which uses a Page Variable they call `slug` that provides a unique, unchanging reference to each page.

For instance, if you'd like to place a link to your impressum.html page (for which the permalink could change), you can place this code on another page, such as index.html:

```
{% for mypage in site.pages %}
 {% if mypage.slug == 'impressum' %}
  <a href="{{ mypage.url }}">Link to Impressum page</a>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, in the YAML frontmatter for each of your pages, place code similar to the following:

```
---
slug: impressum
permalink: /my-permalink-to-impressum/
---
```

To change your permalinks in the future, you would just make the change to the Page Variable `permalink` in each page. The URLs referenced in your other pages would be automatically updated by Jekyll, as long as the `slug` variable remains unchanged.