# Jekyll - declare image path in front matter as variable using {{ site.url }}

Tags: image, yaml, markdown, jekyll

When I use the `{{ site.url }}` tag for an image path inside a variable in the front matter, it doesn't get translated into HTML.

The following works perfectly:

```
---
layout: post
title: chickpea
img: <img class="caption__media" data-interchange="[../asset/img/chickpea-small.jpg (small)], [../asset/img/chickpea-medium.jpg, (medium)], [../asset/img/chickpea-large.jpg, (large)]">
---
```

This does NOT work:

```
---
layout: post
title: chickpea
img: <img class="caption__media" data-interchange="[{{site.url}}/asset/img/chickpea-small.jpg (small)], [{{site.url}}/asset/img/chickpea-medium.jpg, (medium)], [{{site.url}}/asset/img/chickpea-large.jpg, (large)]">
---
```

But when I use the same image link with the `{{site.url}}` tag *inside a post and not as a variable*, it works.

Analysing the generated site shows that Jekyll doesn't convert the `{{site.url}}` tag when I use it in the image variable defined in the front matter.

So the question is: How can I get Jekyll to translate the image path in the YAML front matter correctly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're mixing data and template in the yaml. Your image tag (which is a template) will be duplicated in all your posts. But the only thing you need here are your image urls.

So, in your yaml front matter, do :

```
---
layout: post
title: chickpea
img:
  small:  chickpea-small.jpg
  medium: chickpea-medium.jpg
  large:  chickpea-large.jpg
---
```

And in your layout/post.html you can add :

```
{% if page.img %}
  <img class="caption__media" data-interchange="
  {% for img in page.img %}
    [{{site.baseurl}}/asset/img/{{img[1]}} ({{img[0]}})]
    {% unless forloop.last %}, {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
  ">
{% endif %}
```

*this code is multi-lines for demo purpose. You'd better put all on one line.*

Note: I'm using **{{site.baseurl}}** instead of {{site.url}} because if your site is not at the root of a domain **baseurl** will save you from broken assets paths.

And now you have a clean separation of concerns, clear yaml front matter and maintainable code. Cool isn't it ?

Comment: works perfect!
the only thing i had to edit is i had to change "post" to "page".

how does this array-kind-of adressing of the image in yaml work?
that you adress the first part with img[0] and the second behind the colon with img[1] ?
i cant find any documentation on that :(

Comment: Liquid documentation https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#for-loops

Comment: When i use your recommended code in the post layout, it works perfectly fine. 
When i use it _inside a post_, it seems jekyll doesnt generate the html. the link-text is displayed 1:1 instead of the corresponding image. any clue?
i tried putting it into a div with markdown="1" but that doesnt work. :(

Comment: I now outsourced the image code to the layout file -> less code and cleaner posts :)
Anyway the question resides: why doesnt jekyll generate html out of the same code when its inside a post?

Comment: Code needs to be all on one line : **<img class="caption__media" data-interchange="{% for img in page.img %}[{{site.baseurl}}/asset/img/{{img[1]}} ({{img[0]}})]{% unless forloop.last %}, {% endunless %}{% endfor %}">**

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the problem using this technique:
[Include jekyll / liquid template data in a YAML variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487110/include-jekyll-liquid-template-data-in-a-yaml-variable)

therefore i *changed the use of the variable inside the post* from:

```
{{ post.img }}
```

to:

```
{{ post.img | replace: '..', site.url }}
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem. :)