# Jekyll: using variables in definition of other variables

Tags: variables, jekyll

In Jekyll, is there a way to use a variable in the definition of another variable. For example, I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
---
title: test
var1: {{ page.name }}_foo
var2: bar_{{ page.var1 }}
---
```

However, this results in an error:

> did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to get liquid variables in Jekyll Yaml Front Matter.

[Jekyll - declare image path in front matter as variable using {{ site.url }}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295418/jekyll-declare-image-path-in-front-matter-as-variable-using-site-url)

[Using liquid tags in YAML Front Matter variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392186/using-liquid-tags-in-yaml-front-matter-variables)