# How to reuse yaml fields inside one file

Tags: yaml, jekyll

Is it possible to reuse yaml fields inside one file? Check example below

```
baseurl: '/test'


field1: 'baseurl/qqq'
```

in this case field1 should become `/test/qqq`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487110/include-jekyll-liquid-template-data-in-a-yaml-variable ?

Comment: and it is not possible to reuse yaml variable data inside yaml front matter. you can include it in post though. but the answer here helps in a trick : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487110/include-jekyll-liquid-template-data-in-a-yaml-variable#answer-14650794